# Second Select option didn't get value

Tags: php

Please check my second select box get value, but not get value from 1st select box. Please check my code where I am wrong?

Here is my code:

```
          <select class='form-control' id=class_code name=class_code 
          onchange='setTextField(this)'><option value=''>Select 
          class</option>";
         <option value=$row[class_code] >$row[class]</option>";
             }
        </select>
        <input id='cls' type = 'hidden' name = 'cls' value = '' />
           <script type='text/javascript'>
          function setTextField(dddl) {
               document.getElementById('cls').value = 
            dddl.options[dddl.selectedIndex].text;
               }
            </script>

            <select class='form-control' id=semester_id name=semester_id     
            onchange='setTextField(this)'><option value=''>Select 
             semester</option></select>
            <input id='semm' type = 'hidden' name = 'semm' value = '' />
           <script type='text/javascript'>
          function setTextField(ddl) {
              document.getElementById('semm').value = 
              ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
                }
           </script>
```

Please check where I am wrong. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you post your exact code, what you're expecting, and what you're getting? This doesn't seem to be exact code or correct syntax.

Comment: yes, it's full code. in this first select form didn't get value. please tell me how to do that ??

Comment: If you want a good answer start with a good question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve it.

Comment: This would be more of a javascript issue. Post your rendered code, check your browser console for any errors, and use the javascript tag to get the right eyes on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select class='form-control' id=class_code name=class_code onchange='setTextField1(this)'>
    <option value=''>Select class</option>";
    <option value=$row[class_code]>$row[class]</option>";
</select>
<input id='cls' type = 'hidden' name = 'cls' value = '' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function setTextField1(dddl) {
        document.getElementById('cls').value = dddl.options[dddl.selectedIndex].text;
    }   
</script>

<select class='form-control' id=semester_id name=semester_id onchange='setTextField(this)'>
    <option value=''>Select semester</option>
    <option value='1'>semester1</option>
</select>
<input id='semm' type = 'hidden' name = 'semm' value = '' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function setTextField(ddl) {
          document.getElementById('semm').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Work like a charm please tell me where i am wrong ??

Comment: Your function name is same. So every time execute your one function.